# How to autosort a column in Excel when editing a table

Tags: excel, sorting, automation

I have want to make a sports system so that people can bet each weeks on a few games. So:

```
Name  |  week 1 |  week2 | ... | week 32 |  Total
```

I want every time when I insert some value in the week columns that total table gets sorted.

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: The total is just a sum of all the scores for that player he gets in a week.., and i just want to sort this so that the player with the highest score gets on top

Comment: Yis I want it automatic. It's in the title of the question?

Comment: If you suggest using macro's, I don't even have a clue how to start.. I'd like to know if there is anoher way

Comment: Don't do that!  It's confusing for people when their just-entered data gets moved immediately after they add it.  Instead, add a button which performs the sort.